# ¿Como usar el Number_Field en Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tengo un problema con este tipo de campo que está dentro de mi formulario y es que al tratar de guardar ese valor dentro de mi bd, me asigna automáticamente un cero a dicho campo, por lo que no registra el valor que yo quiero.

Este es el código de mi formulario.

```
     <p> 
      <%= f.label :calificacion, "Calificacion",:class=>"etiqueta" %>
      <br />
      <%= f.number_field :calificacion,{:value => @calificacion,:step => '0.1', :class=>"caja"} %>
   </p>
```

A continuación pondré el código de mi método para almacenar.

```
 def create

   @titulo = params[:pelicula][:titulo];
   @calificacion = params[:pelicula][:calificacion];
   @ano = params[:pelicula][:ano];
      @pais = params[:pelicula][:pais];
   @duracion = params[:pelicula][:duracion];
   @genero = params[:pelicula][:genero];
      @estreno = params[:pelicula][:estreno];
   @fecha_estreno = params[:pelicula][:fecha_estreno];
   @recomendacion = params[:pelicula][:recomendacion];
         @sinopsis = params[:pelicula][:sinopsis];
   @nota = params[:pelicula][:nota];
   @status = params[:pelicula][:status];
   @pelicula = Pelicula.new({
      :titulo => @titulo,
      :calificacion => @calificacion,
      :ano => @ano,
            :pais => @pais,
      :duracion => @duracion,
      :genero => @genero,
            :estreno => @estreno,
      :fecha_estreno => @fecha_estreno,
      :recomendacion => @recomendacion,
            :sinopsis => @sinopsis,
      :nota => @nota,
      :status=>@status
      });
   if @pelicula.save()
      redirect_to peliculas_path, :notice => "La Pelicula ha sido insertada";
   else
      render "new";
   end
  end
```

Y esta es la forma en que inserta en mi bd

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los datos de arriba que si están ingresados se debe a que antes de cambiarlo a number_field era un text_field

Comment: ¿Que te muestra el log cuando grabas los datos? específicamente que te muestra el log de los parametros, como está siendo ejecutado el `INSERT` en la base de datos.

Comment: Punto aparte, ¿estás usando rails 3? desde rails 4 lo normal es usar *Strong parameters* en el controlador. En general es demasiado verbosa esa forma de sacar los parámetros que estás usando, cuando puede ser realizado tan solo en un par de líneas. Revisa https://youtu.be/hJdvGxol96I o http://codehero.co/ruby-on-rails-desde-cero-actioncontroller-parte-2/ para mas info

Answer (score 1):

Sí imprimes con `puts params[:pelicula][:calificacion]` con que obtienes?

Cuando hiciste la migración, en tu base de datos, pusiste ese campo como n `integer` o es un `string`(revisa en tu schema)? Si lo pusiste como string, arregla tu migración para que sea un integer. Sí tu base de datos está bien, puede ser que te esté intentando guardar un string en un campo de integer. Prueba:

```
@calificacion = params[:pelicula][:calificacion].to_i
```

Adicionalmente:

- En ruby no se usa  el `;` al terminar las líneas, solo en caso de que se ejecute más de una instrucción en la misma línea, y en general rompe con varias guías de estilo creo.
- Usa una sola variable de instancia @pelicula, y en tu vista usa `@pelicula.título` y etc.

  (Esto debería estar como comentario, pero me falta rep)